# embed string in the html

Tags: c#, asp.net

Asp.net c#
I am using the below code..

```
 <%String h = "hello";%>
                 <!-- "wall_com_insert.aspx?Tid=" + Application.Get("Tid");-->



      <div id="content_sr_comment" style="height: auto">&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="Label8" 
              runat="server" Text="<%=h%>" ></asp:Label>
        </div>
```

But I am getting the output..

output displayed on the label: "<%=h%>"

I guess the syntax is not correct.. can I get help

Answer (score 2):

You can't place a server command inside a server tag. Try this:

```
<div id="content_sr_comment" style="height: auto">&nbsp;<%= h %></div>
```

Or

```
<script runat="server" language="C#">
    void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String h = "hello";
        Label8.Text = h;
    }
</script>

<div id="content_sr_comment" style="height: auto">&nbsp;
    <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server"></asp:Label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks its working.. but what if I have multiple label tag inside <div></div>

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
<script runat="server" language="C#">
    private string h = "hello";
</script>
<!-- "wall_com_insert.aspx?Tid=" + Application.Get("Tid");-->

<div id="content_sr_comment" style="height: auto">&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="Label8" 
    runat="server"><%=h%></asp:Label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach that I find useful, especially if you want to write out a value in multiple places in your html is to create a function in your code behind like this:

```
protected string SayHello()
{
    return "Hello";
}
```

You can then use it all over your html:

```
<div id="content_sr_comment" style="height: auto">
    <%=SayHello() %>
</div>
```